# Docker Storage Driver overlay2 not showing all the information

Tags: linux, docker, centos, containers

docker info command shows **Storage Driver** as **overlay2** and is not showing information like when **Storage Driver** is **devicemapper** as shown below [image]

Is there a way to see similar sort of information when **Storage Driver** is **overlay2**?

Reason:
docker info shows the following warnings when Storage Driver is devicemapper

> WARNING: the devicemapper storage-driver is deprecated, and will be removed in a future release.

> WARNING: devicemapper: usage of loopback devices is strongly discouraged for production use.

Comment: Which of those lines do you need? Most of them do not apply to overlay2, so why do you need the details may be a more important question. Devicemapper as a docker backend has been deprecated for quite a while now, and your docker version is roughly 5 years old.

Comment: @BMitch I am trying to create an application that collects docker metrics data which you can find on datadog website https://docs.datadoghq.com/containers/docker/data_collected/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Device mapper used a dedicated block device (or loop mounted file as a device) as storage for the images and containers. The various utilization statistics applied to that block devices.

AUFS, Overlay, Overlay2, and other storage backends don't have this block device. They also don't separate between metadata and data storage, they're just different files in folders. To see the remaining capacity of the storage backend, you look at the remaining capacity of the backing filesystem. E.g.

```
df /var/lib/docker
```